# Spotfire Over() function finding for Overall total with multiple categories?

Tags: spotfire

I have a cross table and want to create a column for FG Rate by monthly. my horizontal axis header is Month(column name). my vertical axis is family and description (just added the family previously only description). Below is my formula in cell value axis and i'm using over() function. This gives me the total count inputted in a month and total count of description in a month. Where and how can i Add the Family in over() function to give the total count inputted in a month and by family?

Basically, The cross table gives me overview of the monthly rate of FG that came from the following description at each family. Before it doesn't have the Family in vertical axis only description. 
Thank you in advance.

```
below is my current code:

sum(case  when ([YieldType]="Yield") and ([code]!="9b") and (
[fg_cnt]=1) then 1 end) / Sum(case  when [YieldType]="Yield" then 1 end) 
OVER (All([Axis.Rows])) as [FGRate]
```

Sample actual cross table
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved: use parent instead of ALL.

sum(case  when ([YieldType]="Yield") and ([code]!="9b") and (
   [fg_cnt]=1) then 1 end) / Sum(case  when [YieldType]="Yield" 
   then 1 end) 
   OVER (Parent([Axis.Rows])) as [FGRate]